# CSS - Font Awesome show as rectangle

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I knew this issue already has been asked. I've checked what other said before but I couldn't solve my problem. Whenever I use this:

```
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

For FontAwsome, it works. but I want to add this to my directory so: here is my font's directory:

[image]

And of course I added CSS file into my HTML:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
     .
     .
     .
     <div class="col-md-2 logobarItem">
        <a href="#">text<i class="fa fa-user"></i></a>                      
     </div>
```

And here is my CSS directory:

[image]

Actually , in this situation , font awesome show like rectangle:
[image]

Any suggestion to solve it?

Comment: Are you using bundle optimization?

Comment: @Fred No, I don't use it.

Comment: Check console is fontawesome included or nt this will occur some time for network error

Comment: Your font directry not correct

Comment: @devpro how to check console?

Comment: In firefox a plugin firebug available use it...

Comment: Solution is that check yur font path in fontawesome file is that correct... I have already faced this issue and when I write the full path of font file in fontawesome it works try this

Comment: @afn in all major browsers, you can open the developer tools (and the console) by pressing F12